# How to debug Linux TCP slows/packet loss

Tags: linux, routing, performance, tcp, packet

I'm trying to track down some particular network paths which are slowing down to about 200KByte/sec.  I see this performance through various tests including with `scp`, `rsync` and `iperf3`:

```
$ iperf3 -c 157.130.91.64 -R
Connecting to host 157.130.91.64, port 5201
Reverse mode, remote host 157.130.91.64 is sending
[  5] local 172.16.1.177 port 47862 connected to 157.130.91.64 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   274 KBytes  2.25 Mbits/sec
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   199 KBytes  1.63 Mbits/sec
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   202 KBytes  1.66 Mbits/sec
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   198 KBytes  1.62 Mbits/sec
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec   195 KBytes  1.60 Mbits/sec
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   184 KBytes  1.51 Mbits/sec
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   195 KBytes  1.60 Mbits/sec
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec   209 KBytes  1.71 Mbits/sec
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   192 KBytes  1.58 Mbits/sec
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec   187 KBytes  1.53 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  2.31 MBytes  1.94 Mbits/sec   65             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.99 MBytes  1.67 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

The host in question is on a third party hosting provider.  And I am downloading data to a co-located data center.

I haven't entirely been able to pin down the common element.  There are two routers on my side of the network and then a VM host and then a virtual machine.  The VM host and the inner-most router are using a VxLAN (i.e. via `ip link add vxlan100 type vxlan`...), which I suspect is part of the problem.  However, I can get 1Gbit speeds (measured with iperf3) directly over the VxLAN to various locations within the rack.  I can provide an example but it reads like the above only orders of magnitude faster.

The only clue I have at this point is if I capture traffic while this 200KByte/sec transfer is running I do see a higher incidence of TCP retransmissions, TCP out-of-order, and TCP Dup ACK messages in Wireshark. These do seem to correlate with the slow.  Captured traffic which runs at much higher speeds also has some TCP retransmissions but much fewer in relation to how much traffic is being sent.

My question here is how do I debug this to find the cause of the missing packets?  And are there any specific places I should be checking? It seems like there is some degree of packet loss which is causing this slow, but I'm at a loss as to where to try to find it.  The packet loss itself does not exhibit at slower speeds, nor does it exhibit within machines within my own datacenter.  There seems to be no exact single place where this predictably occurring, only that it definitely occurs between a VM in my datacenter and another machine in another data center.  (And also this other machines does have higher transfer rates to other places like AWS, so it's the third party machine, I've checked, it only reproduces when sending to my network).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just for posterity I'll post an answer as a followup to how I solved this.  I went through several steps and they might be helpful to others trying to track down packet loss.

`iperf3` was an excellent tool to reproduce the issue.

Server: `iperf3 -s`

Client: `iperf3 -c 157.130.91.64 -R` (or without the -R to go the other direction)

I then used `tcpdump` to perform packet logging to a file, but I **ran this packet capture simultaneously at every point I could access**.  Since there are two Linux routers that I control in between the hosts, plus there are VxLANs in use with their own interfaces, it ended up being 9 separate points which I captured with commands like:

```
tcpdump -w /tmp/machineX-eno1.cap
```

I then `scp`ed these files down to my desktop, got a burrito, and used the Wireshark UI to comb through these nine different samples to find out exactly where in the flow packets were being lost.  (Wireshark is pretty awesome as a UI for this, it even does things like unwrap VxLAN traffic so you can see the TCP stream inside.  But I'll use `tcpdump` for the samples below because it's gives nice copy-and-paste-able text output.)

Now, packet loss is normal when saturating a link, but the loss in this case was coming much earlier than would be expected.  For TCP, the "window" is used to keep track of "how much data can be sent before an acknowledgment is required".  The window starts off at a moderate size and is increased as long as performance is improving and there's no packet loss.  In cases where everything was working correctly, the first lost packet would happen many megabytes into the stream.  But in the problem case, it would get only about 260k into the stream before packets go missing.

The packet loss, as shown via `tcpdump -n -r [filename]` from my samples looks like so on the client machine:

```
13:40:00.344219 IP 157.130.91.64.5201 > 172.16.1.177.50298: Flags [.], seq 246161:253401, ack 38, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4032728542 ecr 187200696], length 7240
13:40:00.344232 IP 172.16.1.177.50298 > 157.130.91.64.5201: Flags [.], ack 253401, win 2745, options [nop,nop,TS val 187200770 ecr 4032728542], length 0
13:40:00.345642 IP 157.130.91.64.5201 > 172.16.1.177.50298: Flags [.], seq 253401:260641, ack 38, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4032728542 ecr 187200696], length 7240
13:40:00.345673 IP 172.16.1.177.50298 > 157.130.91.64.5201: Flags [.], ack 260641, win 2858, options [nop,nop,TS val 187200771 ecr 4032728542], length 0
13:40:00.345772 IP 157.130.91.64.5201 > 172.16.1.177.50298: Flags [.], seq 260641:269329, ack 38, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4032728542 ecr 187200696], length 8688
```

Everything looks good up to the last packet above - you can see it transmits up to offset 269329 in the stream as indicated by `seq 260641:269329`.  The trouble awaits at the next packet:

```
13:40:00.345772 IP 157.130.91.64.5201 > 172.16.1.177.50298: Flags [.], seq 301185:304081, ack 38, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4032728543 ecr 187200697], length 2896
```

My goodness, you say, where did the data from 269329 to 301184 go?  Exactly.  This next packet shows data for `seq 301185:304081`.  Sometimes packets can arrive out of order, but looking through the stream the data in question is nowhere to be found.

We get further confirmation of this by looking at the `ack`s that follow:

```
13:40:00.345805 IP 172.16.1.177.50298 > 157.130.91.64.5201: Flags [.], ack 269329, win 2994, options [nop,nop,TS val 187200771 ecr 4032728542], length 0
13:40:00.345857 IP 172.16.1.177.50298 > 157.130.91.64.5201: Flags [.], ack 269329, win 3039, options [nop,nop,TS val 187200771 ecr 4032728542,nop,nop,sack 1 {301185:304081}], length 0
13:40:00.345934 IP 157.130.91.64.5201 > 172.16.1.177.50298: Flags [.], seq 304081:306977, ack 38, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4032728543 ecr 187200697], length 2896
13:40:00.345934 IP 157.130.91.64.5201 > 172.16.1.177.50298: Flags [.], seq 306977:309873, ack 38, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4032728543 ecr 187200697], length 2896
13:40:00.345934 IP 157.130.91.64.5201 > 172.16.1.177.50298: Flags [.], seq 309873:312769, ack 38, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4032728543 ecr 187200697], length 2896
13:40:00.345935 IP 157.130.91.64.5201 > 172.16.1.177.50298: Flags [.], seq 312769:314217, ack 38, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4032728543 ecr 187200697], length 1448
13:40:00.345971 IP 172.16.1.177.50298 > 157.130.91.64.5201: Flags [.], ack 269329, win 3084, options [nop,nop,TS val 187200771 ecr 4032728542,nop,nop,sack 1 {301185:306977}], length 0
13:40:00.345995 IP 172.16.1.177.50298 > 157.130.91.64.5201: Flags [.], ack 269329, win 3129, options [nop,nop,TS val 187200772 ecr 4032728542,nop,nop,sack 1 {301185:309873}], length 0
13:40:00.346005 IP 172.16.1.177.50298 > 157.130.91.64.5201: Flags [.], ack 269329, win 3175, options [nop,nop,TS val 187200772 ecr 4032728542,nop,nop,sack 1 {301185:312769}], length 0
13:40:00.346011 IP 172.16.1.177.50298 > 157.130.91.64.5201: Flags [.], ack 269329, win 3197, options [nop,nop,TS val 187200772 ecr 4032728542,nop,nop,sack 1 {301185:314217}], length 0
```

You can see `ack 269329` being sent repeatedly from the client back to the server, indicating that the client is saying it has only received the full set of packets up to that point in the stream, and is missing the data that follows it.

Now, if we examine the tcpdump from the router (the "next hop" up), we find that it says it was in fact received (and forwarded - this is from the ingress interface, which is why the destination IPs are different due to NAT, but the egress shows the same packets):

```
13:40:00.356167 IP 157.130.91.64.5201 > 32.133.287.15.50298: Flags [.], seq 253401:273673, ack 38, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4032728542 ecr 187200696], length 20272
13:40:00.356235 IP 157.130.91.64.5201 > 32.133.287.15.50298: Flags [.], seq 273673:293945, ack 38, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4032728543 ecr 187200696], length 20272
13:40:00.356291 IP 157.130.91.64.5201 > 32.133.287.15.50298: Flags [.], seq 293945:301185, ack 38, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4032728543 ecr 187200697], length 7240
13:40:00.356367 IP 157.130.91.64.5201 > 32.133.287.15.50298: Flags [.], seq 301185:304081, ack 38, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 4032728543 ecr 187200697], length 2896
```

So it's pretty clear the router thinks it sent the packets, and the host never received them.

Investigating this further, I observed some other really interesting pieces to the puzzle:

- **These packets are larger than the MTU of 1500 bytes.**  Now the 1500 MTU does not count the link layer, so the ethernet header is not counted in that.  But still these packets are like 20k, what the..
- **This is caused by "large send offload"/LSO (and conversely "large receive offload"/LRO)** which essentially let's the OS send and receive these large packets to/from the network card and the network card will rewrite the necessary headers (including the TCP header) to form a semantically equivalent set of packets that matches the MTU.  So the OS sends a 20k packet, and the network card makes a dozen packets and sends them out, each one less than 1500 bytes.  And does the inverse when receiving.
- **You can disable LSO, LRO and other hardware optimizations** if you want to remove this from the equation and also get a better idea of exactly what is being sent out - using `ethtool`, e.g. `ethtool -K enp12s0 rx off tx off sg off tso off gso off gro off lro off rxvlan off txvlan off rxhash off`
- In my case, this actually did make an improvement, but not enough. Instead of about 1.5Mbit, I was getting 10Mbit - on a 1Gbit network card.
- **One can also use `ethtool` to look for errors**, e.g. `ethtool -S enp12s0 | grep err` - that can yield some interesting stuff.  Look up the individual errors you find if there are any, but it could be the source the problem.
- **In some cases, while capturing with tcpdump on one of the routers, running tcpdump improved performance** (which is super strange to me). Apparently this may be caused by some buffer being emptied earlier, etc., but by this time, it's pretty clear which device the problem is appearing on - if you can do some packet logging and have a major improvement on performance, that's a pretty good indicator you're monitoring the device that is the source of the problem.
- **Also, to be sure, you'll want to check cables, SFP adapters, switch ports and like** (none of which were the issue in my case)

Bottom line: Dump packets and narrow down where in the network the problem is, then use ideas from above or whatever else you can think of to see if it's the underlying cause, use iperf3 to easily simulate the condition to determine if what you just changed had the desired (or further undesired) effect.

In my case it turned out to be a machine I was using as a Linux router purchased from an unreliable source (which I will not name directly but rhymes with "blamazon") and had errors showing in ethtool.  But it's important to note that MOST TRAFFIC WAS FINE through this router, it was only specific patterns of traffic which would exhibit the packet loss shown above.  So casual connection tests would all pass, but under specific loads packets would be lost and connections would be slow.  But ultimately, the unruly device was found and eliminated using the procedure described above.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the report